# Problem in C - How to erase a array in a database struct

Tags: c, windows, database

include files:

```
stdio.h
string.h
ctype.h
genlib.h
simpio.h
strlib.h
```

The database struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct{

    catT *cats;
    int currentMaxSize;
    int currentNumberOfCats;
    int nextId;

} *DBT;
```

and the "cats" struct looks like this:

```
typedef struct {

    int id;
    string name;
    char gender;
    int birthYear;
    int numberOfColours;
    string colours[MAX_COLOURS];

} catT;
```

---

If we say I got 3 cats in the DBT database and want to erase 
one of them, how can i code it? I want to have a function to erase 
a cat!

Answer (score 1):

Well, the size of catT is fixed. Which is good.

If you want to erase the last cat in the list, then it's easy. Just use realloc() so make your DBT smaller. (new size will be 2*sizeof(catT)).

If you want to remove a cat that is not the last cat in the list, then change that. If you don't care about sorting then just override the cat which you want to delete with the last cat in the list (do this using memcpy()). Then you can remove the last cat in the list.

Answer (score 1):

```
void freeCat(int atIndex, DBT db)
{
    if (atIndex < db->currentNumberOfCats)
    {
        if (atIndex < db->currentNumberOfCats - 1)
        {            
            memmove(db->cats + atIndex, 
                    db->cats + atIndex + 1, 
                    db->currentNumberOfCats - atIndex - 1);
        }
        db->currentNumberOfCats--;
    }
}
```

But this is expensive. If you are going to repeatedly erase cats, use a linked list or consider allocating `catT` on the heap (`catT **cats`), so you only have to move the pointers around (don't forget to `free` the cat then).

Comment: Daniel Gehriger, this is nearly what i'm looking for, the only poblem is that it is the last cat which is removed and the cat i want to remove just gets the ID of the cat after!

Comment: Not sure I understand... can you rephrase?

Comment: the thing is that the cat (with index I want to remove) just gets a higher ID, let say I want to remove the cat on index 0. That cats ID will increase with one, and the last cat will not be written (because db->currentNumberOfCats--)... The thing is that this functon do not erase a cat, just inrease the cats ID with 1?

Comment: @FredrichP: I think there is a mix up between cat ids and the indices into the array. Erasing a cat does not change the `id` member of any of the cats. And I assumed that `currentNumberOfCats` is unrelated to the `id`, it's just number of cats (their `id` could be anything). If, however, the `id` has to match the array index, then either get rid of that member entirely, or renumber after moving.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you will allocate memory for 3 cats with `*cats` of `DBT`.
To erase one of the cats, you need to free the memory for the cat you want to erase.
I can't write the code since I don't know the variables and functions you use but I hope this gives you some idea.

Answer (score 0):

void freeCat(int atIndex, DBT db)
{
    int i;

```
if (atIndex < db->currentNumberOfCats)
{         
    if (atIndex < db->currentNumberOfCats - 1)
    {
        for(i = atIndex; i < db->currentNumberOfCats; i++){
            db->cats[i] = db->cats[i+1];
        }
    }         
    db->currentNumberOfCats--;
}
```

}

I did this function and it works perfect! Thanks everyone and @Daniel Gehriger for the start of the function, this helped me very much!